# Disable the red border in android ICS?

Tags: android

When I open a new application in android, the red border shows up in ICS builds for other platforms as well.And it stays for one or two seconds.I want to disable it. Can You please tell me how to disable the red frame border in android?
Thanks in advance...Please Help Me..

Comment: happens in emulator or in real device?

Comment: This question belongs to the [Android Enthusiast](http://android.stackexchange.com) community since it's not a development related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.
"Settings > Developer Options > (under) User interface > (uncheck) Strict Mode"
this answer works when lunch mode is user Mode and it won't work when lunch is in Eng Mode.
I found code in DevelopmentSettings.java in Settings application.
The code is as follows.

```
private void removeHdcpOptionsForProduction() {
    if ("user".equals(Build.TYPE)) {
        Preference hdcpChecking = findPreference(HDCP_CHECKING_KEY);
        if (hdcpChecking != null) {
            // Remove the preference
            getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(hdcpChecking);
        }
    }
}
```

So I removed the condition checking ..

Comment: You are on the right track BUT the code you included has nothing to do with the strict mode visual indicator. That is located in StricMode.java https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/java/android/os/StrictMode.java - see starting at line 931:
```
    // Eng builds have flashes on all the time.  The suppression property
    // overrides this, so we force the behavior only after the short-circuit
   // check above.
    if (IS_ENG_BUILD) {
       doFlashes = true;
    }
```

Comment: Thank u so much. Yes You are right I need to disable it in StrictMode.java @Maks

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Settings -> Developer Options -> Disable Strict mode .
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this is caused by the `ICS update`. I encountered this with my Device.

Try to go to

> Settings > Developer Options > (under) User interface > (uncheck)
>   Strict Mode

I'm not sure if we have the same settings setup. Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: if this step still doesnt help you, reboot your device and it will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

> Can You please tell me how to disable the red frame border in android?

You are spending too much time on the main application thread, and the device has settings (noted in the other answers) for displaying such problems via the red border flash.

While adjusting the settings gets rid of the flash, it does not get rid of your flawed code that is spending too much time on the main application thread. Whether you use `StrictMode` in your code, or use Traceview to identify slow spots, you need to stop blocking the main application thread.